# Extending Javascript objects with CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

I want to add the ability to extend javascript objects by adding a method to the prototype.
The method will receive one or more other objects and will add all of the key/values to `this`.
This is what I came up with:

```
Object::extend = (objects...) ->
    @[key] = value for key, value of object for object in objects
```

or this:

```
Object::extend = (objects...) ->
    for object in objects
        for key, value of object
            @[key] = value
```

Both work as expected, and compile into the same javascript code:

```
var __slice = [].slice;

Object.prototype.extend = function() {
  var key, object, objects, value, _i, _len, _results;
  objects = 1 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = objects.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    object = objects[_i];
    _results.push((function() {
      var _results1;
      _results1 = [];
      for (key in object) {
        value = object[key];
        _results1.push(this[key] = value);
      }
      return _results1;
    }).call(this));
  }
  return _results;
};
```

What I'm not too happy about is the whole results thing that is created per for loop which is completely redundant for my purpose.
Is there a way to get a code more like:

```
Object.prototype.extend = function() {
  var key, object, objects, value, _i, _len;
  objects = 1 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = objects.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    object = objects[_i];
    (function() {
      for (key in object) {
        value = object[key];
        this[key] = value;
      }
    }).call(this);
  }
};
```

Thanks.

---

## Edit

I'm aware that I can simply [embed](http://coffeescript.org/#embedded) javascript code, but looking for a coffeescript solution.

Comment: Have you noticed the `coffeescript` tag? The javascript code is the result of compiling coffeescript into javascript, I did not write that js code.

Comment: Just noticed that and removed my comment immediately... Oops.

Comment: Yuck, modifying `Object.prototype`

Comment: Yeah, I know, this was just to test a few things

Comment: The code above can be updated with a check for properties object's only and leave the properties inherited from prototype away. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bogdan_vq/fWzVG/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try adding an explicit `return`:

```
Object::extend = (objects...) ->
    for object in objects
        for key, value of object
            @[key] = value
    return
```

That produces this:

```
var __slice = [].slice;

Object.prototype.extend = function() {
  var key, object, objects, value, _i, _len;
  objects = 1 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = objects.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    object = objects[_i];
    for (key in object) {
      value = object[key];
      this[key] = value;
    }
  }
};
```

Every CoffeeScript function returns the value of the last expression in the function, CoffeeScript loops are also expressions. That means that CoffeeScript has to build all that `_results` stuff to produce a return value for your function since you had an implicit `return` applying to the outer loop. If you remove that implicit `return` by adding an explicit "return nothing" then the CS→JS compiler seems to be smart enough to not do all that extra `_results` work.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for! Though I went with my first version. Thank you.

Comment: It is better to return @ in the end to make possibility of chain calls .